# Share data within forms through class

Tags: c#, class

I have created a class with below code

```
Public class userdetail
{
Public string username{get;set;}
Public string password{get; set;}
}
```

Here i am trying to set the valur from my login form but after the forms changes.. the value of this variable becomes Null..

Comment: I'm afraid your question isn't complete enough - which variable becomes null?  Are you using a web form or a desktop application?  What code gets executed to set your value?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't “set the valur from my login form”. and all values will be null because you never set them to anything.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you are using your forms. Your question was not clear or specific. If you have a userdata class object you created in form1 and then form1 opens form2 you could add a new constructor to form2 that accepts a userdata object as an argument then save it to a member variable in form2.